# How to get the integer value of day of week

Tags: c#, datetime, dayofweek, date-conversion

How do I get the day of a week in integer format? I know ToString will return only a string.

```
DateTime ClockInfoFromSystem = DateTime.Now;
int day1;
string day2;
day1= ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek.ToString(); /// it is not working
day2= ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek.ToString(); /// it gives me string
```

Comment: @Joe, I was unable to reformat his code for placing his code in code block, why is that?

Comment: You're calling `ToString()` so why would you expect anything but a string?

Comment: @Dave, I had to separate it a line from the text of the question, or else it just indented the code...

Comment: cool! I was trying to make his code into codeblock & it dint allow me to do.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Use

```
day1 = (int)ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: it will return 0 for monday and so on ?

Comment: @developer Sunday is 0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Comment: If you want monday to be 0, just shift the days: `day1 = (int)(ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7`

Comment: If you want to do it faster, take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22278311/3315914

Answer (score 108):

```
int day = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

First day of the week: Sunday (with a value of zero)

Answer (score 82):

If you want to set first day of the week to Monday with integer value 1 and Sunday with integer value 7

```
int day = ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == 0) ? 7 : (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Up-voted as all sane people would want this. ISO 8601 is quite clear on the point. Monday is day 1, Sunday is day 7.

Comment: Didn't release the DayOfWeek property would return zero on sunday. Almost introduced a bug by implementing the top voted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
day1= (int)ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: @JustinSatyr - FiveTools was clearly just giving an example.  It is not his fault the author was attempting to set a String value to an integer variable.

Comment: @Ramhound: I didn't downvote and I wasn't criticizing. I thought he misread the code. And apparently I was correct by the fact that he corrected his code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It will work just fine:

```
int week = Convert.ToInt32(currentDateTime.DayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to get the integer value of an Enum such as DayOfWeek as a string is:

```
DayOfWeek.ToString("d")
```

Comment: This will return a `string`, not an `int`.

Comment: This is day of month not day of week

Comment: @Fritz no it's not, its an enum integer "as a string" as I said. You are getting confused with date formatting which this is not.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get Monday with integer value 1 and Sunday with integer value 7

```
int day = ((int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7 + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer, is indeed the correct answer to get the int value.

But, if you're just checking to make sure it's Sunday for example... Consider using the following code, instead of casting to an int. This provides much more readability.

```
if (yourDateTimeObject.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    // You can easily see you're checking for sunday, and not just "0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
int week = (int) currentDateTime.DayOfWeek;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Readability counts.**

If you need an integer:

```
int day1 = (int)ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek;
```

If you need a string of the weekday integer:

```
string daystr = $"{(int)ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek}"; // Unambiguous string of int.
```

Do not use the recommended ToString conversion, because the majority of programmers are going to have to look it up to make sure that it's a string of the integer and not day of month. Really Microsoft?

```
string daystr = ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek.ToString("d"); // Whaa? Horrible! Don't do this.
```

To change to start of week, add the number of days from Sunday mod 7. Count backwards from Sunday to get the number of days, e.g. 1 back from Sunday is Saturday, 2 back from Sunday is Friday, etc.

```
int satStart = (int)(ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek + 1) % 7; // Saturday start
int monStart = (int)(ClockInfoFromSystem.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7; // Monday start
```