# Get the Day of a week from integer value of the Day

Tags: c#, asp.net, dayofweek

I have converted several days of the week to their respective integer values..

For example: `Tuesday, Thursday, Friday` As `2,4,5`

Now I need to get back to the days from the integers.

Simply the inverse of what i had done.

Inverse of the Question:
[Get Integer value of day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199080/how-to-get-the-integer-value-of-day-of-week)

**Is there a simple standard way for getting day of week from integer value in C# or else I will have to perform a manual calculation with a Method?**

Comment: you mean if user enters 5 it should return Friday right?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try below code :-

```
Response.Write(Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek),5));
```

Output:

`Friday`

and If you have to convert integers to days of week, see following sample to convert “2,4,5″ using LINQ.

```
var t = string.Join(",",
                 from g in "2,4,5".Split(new char[] { ',' })
                 select Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), Convert.ToInt32(g)));
        Response.Write(t);
```

Output:

```
Tuesday,Thursday,Friday
```

For extra informations :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, also for the additional LINQ type conversion.

Answer (score 24):

Try

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[day No]
```

Comment: what if he wants for multiple numbers like 1,2,3?

Comment: And in case some is looking for abbreviations:
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames[day No]

Comment: Awesome answer, uses Framework BCL rather than needing to code.

Answer (score 9):

Adding my answer in case it's any use to anyone:

```
((DayOfWeek)i).ToString();
```

Gives 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday etc

For 0 = Monday just shift along 1

```
((DayOfWeek)((i + 1) % 7)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek),"0")
```

where "0" is string equivalent of integer value of day of the week

Answer (score 2):

In `DateTime.Now` `DayOfWeek` is an enum value and you can get its string value by parsing it to corresponding values.

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(DayofWeek),"0")
```

You will get your desired result then.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Format("{0:dddd}", value)
```

Using enumeration doesn't factor in localisation. This string format should return the full day name as a string localised to local culture.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = DateTime.Today;
        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:dddd}", value));
    }
}
```

Console output on 11th of March 2020, locale en-GB:

```
Wednesday
```

Comment: This returns "dddd"

Comment: Not on my machine... I have included a sample in the answer