# Is there a way that I can get a numeric value for the day of the week with DateTime?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
int intDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

But that's not working.

Is there a way that I can get an integer value for the day of the week?

Comment: Do you get an error? Which one? What happens if you google for that error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the integer value of day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199080/how-to-get-the-integer-value-of-day-of-week) The exact duplicate

Comment: `DayOfWeek` is an `Enum`, not an int, you need to cast it

Comment: `int intDay = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;` 0 is sunday, 6 is saturday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it, as with any other enum:

```
int intDay = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know what number Sunday returns?

Comment: @Alan2 0 as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8#fields).

Comment: Thank you, will accept.